# Any spring MVC sample app using hibernate , DI , AOP

Tags: java, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [spring MVC sample web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777946/spring-mvc-sample-web-app)

I installed spring petcare example for spring 3 but that looks very simple to petcare clinic. but i am not able to find petclinic for spring 3.

Is there any other sample app using spring MVC , hibernate , DI , AOP in one app which also explains its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.earldouglas.com/barebones-spring-mvc) is a series of articles I wrote which resulted in an [e-book](http://www.earldouglas.com/system/files/barebones-spring-mvc.pdf) about Spring MVC, and includes the topics you're asking about.  If there is anything there that you need in more detail, I would be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Spring Roo uses all of those technologies by default.  [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html) is the Roo tutorial if you want to step through that.