# what is data binding used in spring jsp views

Tags: java, spring, jsp, binding, spring-mvc

I can't fully understand the purpose of data binding in jsp of spring. Does someone have a full understanding of it?

Comment: @Name Please do tell us what have you understood and we will build from there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data binding you are referring to?

Comment: i don't anything bout binding. Any docs to learn that

Comment: @Name Please refer to the answer that you accepted to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900663/any-spring-mvc-sample-app-using-hibernate-di-aop. Did you understand how the BindableEmployee object data is displayed in employee.jsp in that ebook that James referred to in his answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have html on one side, and java objects on the other side. You have to convert between these two. That's what binding is for - you tell spring to handle this conversion, i.e. to bind html inputs to object fields.

Answer (score 1):

Classically, data binding was used within applications to take advantage of data stored in databases. Windows Forms data binding allows you to access data.

look at this
www.dapfor.com

Answer (score 0):

typically in a web app, data is loaded from a database.  This is *not* done in the jsp layer (typically).  The databinding is simply  a way to get your data (i.e. model objects) available on the jsps.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to access your input form / URL parameters in an OO fashion: `input.getUserName()`, `input.getBirthDate()`. Spring (as well as other web frameworks, but in different ways) provides you with means of transparently "binding" the input.

This binding process involves conversion (from a Strings to whatever -- Date objects, numbers, your custom classes etc.) and validation, so you get all that out of the box (all you need to do is sometimes configure it to work as you want it).

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML came with **stateless**, binding data came to **resolve** that **problem**.