# Basic Spring MVC web app causes "ContextLoaderListener" error

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create my first Spring MVC web app. I've downloaded Spring Tool Suite and followed these instructions:

> To setup a new project in STS: Click File -> New -> Spring Template
>   Project -> Spring MVC Project To pull in dependencies and compile your
>   project: Right click your new project -> Run As -> Maven install To
>   run your project inside an application server: Right click your new
>   project -> Run As -> Run on Server -> SpringSource tc Server If it
>   works, you'll see a web page saying "Congratulations! You're running
>   Spring!"
>   (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444805/866447)

But when I start the server I always get the following error:

```
Mrz 29, 2012 12:29:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
Warnung: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:undnochmal' did not find a matching property.
[TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader@db27fb2] warning ignoring duplicate definition: jar:file:/C:/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.4.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-collection-1.5.1.SR2.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader@db27fb2] warning ignoring duplicate definition: jar:file:/C:/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.4.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-plugin-jdbc-1.5.1.SR2.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader@db27fb2] warning ignoring duplicate definition: jar:file:/C:/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.4.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-collection-1.5.1.SR2.jar!/META-INF/aop-ajc.xml
[TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader@db27fb2] warning ignoring duplicate definition: jar:file:/C:/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.4.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-plugin-jdbc-1.5.1.SR2.jar!/META-INF/aop-ajc.xml
[TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader@db27fb2] warning ignoring duplicate definition: jar:file:/C:/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.4.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-plugin-tomcat-1.5.1.SR2.jar!/META-INF/aop-ajc.xml
ASPECTJ: aspectj.overweaving=true: overweaving switched ON
Mrz 29, 2012 12:29:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Schwerwiegend: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    ... 20 more
```

I'm totally confused... I used the default IDE with the default SpringMVC Template and the default server. What was wrong? Or do I have to do some obligatory steps before, that are written nowhere?

Comment: I think it might be due to Jar conflict, Check the jar files in application run time (in this case WEB-INF/lib), Also you can do this (Ctrl+Shirt+T) looks for the file and see if it is part of two jars in your class path.

Answer (score 7):

You should include "spring-context"

For example this configuration will throw the failure that you get.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Correct version is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Be sure that the library get coppied to the lib directory.